Ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addMethod')"
Всем привет!
Выдается ошибка в косноли: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addMethod')
На проекте подключаю jQuery и Validate для формы.
На локальной разработке в ветке задачи и в develop ветке - все норм отрабатывает.
На тестовом контуре (там ветка develop) выдает эту ошибку.
В чем может быть причина?


jQuery и плагин Validate подключены ДО скрипта основного.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Возможный дубликат вопроса Почему возникает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addMethod'). Суть ошибки в том, что то, откуда вы пытаетесь вызвать метод addMethod является undefined

проблема в тестовом контуре, либо в разном коде

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or null (reading ***)
